# Do we use "reception" for "Internet", for example, "My Internet reception is bad"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I heard some people say that "**reception**" is for broadcast signals. And that is whey we often hear people say:

*My Phone/TV/radio reception is bad*

But is "**phone signal**" broadcast?

And "**Phone**" is too general. It could refer to a lane phone or mobile phone.

I often hear "**Internet connection is bad**".

Do we use "**reception**" for "**Internet**", for example, "**My Internet reception is bad**"?

Answer (score 2):

"Reception" is appropriate for a wireless signal. That could include phone reception, Wi-Fi, or mobile internet.

"Connection" works for either a wireless or wired signal.